# Datetime format detection Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, date, datetime

I want to use python3 to do the date format detection for example
I have `file1 = "test_20180101234523.txt"`
and the output should be the format type `%Y%M%D%H%m%S` and expected datetime format `2018-01-01,23:45:23`

Here's what I did so far,

```
import re
file1 = "test_20180101234523.txt"
pattern = r'[0-9]{14}'
regex=re.compile(pattern)
matches = regex.findall(file1)
matchesStr = matches[0]
matchesYear = int(matchesStr[0:4])
matchesMonth = int(matchesStr[4:6])
matchesdate = int(matchesStr[6:8])
matchesH = int(matchesStr[8:10])
matchesM = int(matchesStr[10:12])
matchesS = int(matchesStr[12:14])

def checkdate():
    if matchesYear > 1900:
        print("%Y")
    else:
        print("Year is not format")

    if matchesMonth >= 1 and matchesMonth <= 12:
         print("%M")
    else:
        print("Month is not format") 

    if matchesdate >= 1 and matchesdate <= 31:
         print("%d")
    else:
        print("Date is not format")

    if matchesH >= 1 and matchesH <= 24:
         print("%H")
    else:
        print("Hour is not a format")

    if matchesM >= 1 and matchesM <= 60:
        print("%m")                   
    else:
        print("Min is not a format")

    if matchesS >= 1 and matchesS <= 60:
        print("%S")                   
    else:
        print("Sec is not a format")
```

I use regex to find out the group of integer and substring those to be each variable that I need. And use if-else condition to check each of those.
If you guys have any other idea, could you share, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the digits in your inputs are always 14 digits, then you can use`datetime.strptime` with `regex` along with this code to have your desired output:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime


def get_integers(file_name, prefix='test_'):
    """Return matched integers"""
    regex = re.compile(r'{prefix}(\d+)'.format(prefix=prefix))
    matched = re.findall(regex, file_name)
    return matched[0] if matched else ''


def get_datetime_object(date_string):
    """Return datetime object from date_string if it exists"""
    try:
        date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        return date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return None



file1 = 'test_20180101234523.txt'
integers = get_integers(file1)
date = get_datetime_object(integers)
print(date)
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01,23:45:23
```

**PS:** Notice, if the integers in the input are'nt 14 digits, then you should adapt `get_integers` function to return string that contains 14 digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got idea from your post. but the expected output that I want to be is `test_20180101234523.txt --> 2018-01-01,23:45:23 with format %Y%m%d%H%M%`. BTW here's challenges that I got 

`test_20180101234523.txt --> 2018-01-01,23:45:23 with format %Y%m%d%H%M%
 test_2018-01-01.txt -->2018-01-01 with format %Y-%m-%d
 test_01012018.txt --> 01012018 with format %d%m%Y
 test_12345667.txt --> NOT A DATE
 test_20181332.txt --> NOT A DATE
 test_2018123.txt --> 2018243 Julian date
 test_20180101_20180101234452.txt --> 20180101 + format`

Comment: @GDernLwin So you have a non regular inputs ? Can you summarize their edges and can you verify if the inputs are not random ones ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) as (Assuming the regex output will be 14 digit everytime and follows same format):

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('20180101234523', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S')

'2018-01-01,23:45:23'
```

Comment: It will be better to put strptime in a try - except (ValueError) here?